# How to update Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

A mac newbie question: I have an older version of Xcode and want to update it to a newer version. How do I do that?

Comment: For the command line tools, this answer is also very good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617930/2776727

Answer (score 42):

Just an extension to this. I'm using OSX Lion and you can install/update via the App Store.

Comment: Unfortunately you need to provide your creditcard number to enable updating though the App store... In that case, I'll just download it from the website.

Comment: It is possible to create an account **without** providing a credit card, but it must be done in a very specific way: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534 I did it way back when and I'm able to download (free) apps from the App Store without a credit card.

Answer (score 34):

To update Xcode, sadly, you have to download the entire .dmg file from Apple's website again.

Comment: Seriously? Like all the 10 giggs + again?

Comment: It depends now. Xcode 4 (via Lion) is supposed to now do delta updates that are much smaller. Unfortunately, this hasn't come up in practice yet for an installation - there has only been a single 4.1.1 update that was just an installer fix. For Xcode 3, you need to download the whole .dmg again. It's not 10 GB - it's just 2 or 3 :P

Comment: Just downloaded, thanks for the info. I guess there are some strong downsides of doing incremental updates but hopefully they can work something out in the near future.

Comment: Although this likely _was_ the correct answer when the question was originally asked, today you can update via the App Store, per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12065167/320399

Comment: @b.long No you cant. You still need to install each version differently. Especially if you have developer previews or betas installed. I just tried it and I have probably 10 different versions of xcode installed as a result. This has to be the single dumbest thing apple has ever done.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing into a different folder in the root of your hard drive. I have had problems in the past, not with this specific upgrade, that were fixed by doing a fresh install.

Comment: I've never heard of this issue, but if it's a concern, you're better off uninstalling your previous version before installing rather than having two different point versions of developer tools on your system. That said, upgrading Xcode has been pretty painless for any recent build I've used.

Comment: Right now I have 2.5, 3.1.4, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.2.6, 4.0 installed on my main development machine. The problem I was referring to was somewhere in the Xcode 2.x (Panther or Tiger version of the OS) when you could only have one blessed Developer folder on your system and I forgot to uninstall first, so I renamed the old folder and did a "fresh" install. If I continue on for another couple of weeks without any problems running 3.2.6 I'll remove the other 3.2 versions.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac **open the App Store and look for an Xcode update**. You may need to update OS X first if, for example, there was an update to Command Line Tools (see also [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool)) required by the Xcode update.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I cannot see it in the AppStore Update section I searched for it in the AppStore and once I saw Xcode in the search results it displays a button below it saying "Update" if you are not in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 10.7.5 to 10.11.5 on my pro and it rendered my old Xcode (4.4.1) unusable on the new OS. I had to download a new version from App Store. I guess the update feature is not enabled yet in Xcode 4 (as @Dominic mentioned)