# Not able to install bibliometrix under R 3.6.1, with conda environment

Tags: r, conda, install.packages

I would like to install bibliometrix package under R 3.6.1 but failed. It seems that the C++ compiler of my Mac does not correspond with the package requirement.

```
install.packages("bibliometrix")
```

```
also installing the dependencies ‘polyclip’, ‘ggforce’, ‘ggraph’

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/polyclip_1.10-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 79619 bytes (77 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 77 KB

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggforce_0.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 857393 bytes (837 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 837 KB

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggraph_1.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2607278 bytes (2.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.5 MB

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bibliometrix_2.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4649396 bytes (4.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘polyclip’ ...
** 成功将‘polyclip’程序包解包并MD5和检查
** using staged installation
compiling under C++11
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/99/lxnbdsys4_95hcvfp98rkjr80000gp/T/RtmpPPQJJS/R.INSTALL694939cbda46/polyclip':
configure: error: cannot run C++ compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘polyclip’
* removing ‘/Users/Excited_Lee/miniconda3/lib/R/library/polyclip’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘polyclip’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘polyclip’ is not available for package ‘ggforce’
* removing ‘/Users/Excited_Lee/miniconda3/lib/R/library/ggforce’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggforce’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ggforce’ is not available for package ‘ggraph’
* removing ‘/Users/Excited_Lee/miniconda3/lib/R/library/ggraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggraph’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ggraph’ is not available for package ‘bibliometrix’
* removing ‘/Users/Excited_Lee/miniconda3/lib/R/library/bibliometrix’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bibliometrix’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/99/lxnbdsys4_95hcvfp98rkjr80000gp/T/RtmpZkQMzg/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

I tried under Jupyter and Rstudio but same error appeared. My system info is showed below:

```
(base) usddeiMac:~ Excited_Lee$ conda -V
conda 4.7.11
(base) usddeiMac:~ Excited_Lee$ r --version
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56364797/8386140

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work

Comment: Looking at the error message, it begins when it tries to compile the program for your operating system. It could be due to other system dependencies, config or could even privilege issue. The discussion [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/12323#issuecomment-295744796) might help. It involves updating `Xcode` and your `PATH`.

Comment: Here a tried and tested guide for setting up compilers on MacOS: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: Tried. Still fail @Ralf Stubner

Comment: Did you install R from CRAN or via `conda`?

Comment: `conda` @Ralf Stubner

Comment: I have heared in the past that mixing conda with CRAN does not work well. You could try to install the corresponding conda packages, e.g. `r-polyclip`.