# After Mac Mojave update: gfortran error "ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: xcode, gcc, homebrew, gfortran, macos-mojave

After updating to MacOS Mojave, I get an error when compiling with gfortran.

```
gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘18.0.0
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This error did not occur before the update. I tracked similar threads and followed their proposed solutions. However, I got further errors when following ...

- Update XCode: Now updated to version 10.0.
- Run `xcode-select --install`: I get the following error: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line), I did `softwareupdate --list` and get `No new software available.`. I conclude, that XCode updating is not the problem here. I also made sure that additional tools are installed upon first opening the updated XCode.
- Following [this thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/45011), where a similar error was reported, I did `brew doctor`. Something goes wrong here. I get `Warning: Your Xcode (1) is outdated; Please update to Xcode 7.1.` Apparently it doesn't recognise to confirmed fact that my XCode is at 10.0. What can be done about that?
- Following [this thread](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19588#issuecomment-266979910), I did `brew upgrade gcc` and get this error: `Warning: You are using OS X 10.14.; ...`.
- With so many brewing errors, I checked the [brew troubleshooting site](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md), and followed their recommendations. I did `cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var opt Cellar Caskroom Frameworks` and again `brew update` and get this error: `Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable. ...`.  Following the recommendation in the error message, I did `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` but get the error `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`.
- `brew reinstall gcc` sounds like I would get the same error as in the previous point. Haven't tried so far, worrying for making the mess even worse.

Bottom line: I drowned in errors and see no solution. Any ideas what's the problem and how to solve it are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same problems (I think the crt1.0 error relates to the usage of Fortran commands like GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT), and also didn't have any luck after trying all the steps you describe in your post, but it got fixed instantly when I installed gfortran 8.2 for MacOS 10.14 with the installer that you can find here: https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases (got there via the gcc website: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS).

I hope this also fixes the problems for you!