# NPM install node-rdkafka fails with node-gyp rebuild error

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, apache-kafka

I am trying to install `node-rdkafka` using npm and seeing the below error

- OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- node version: 10.16.3 tried (8.x, 12.x and 13.x) as well via `nvm`

```
/Users/VMac/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: line 5: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js: No such file or directory
npm WARN kafka-log-parser@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! node-rdkafka@2.7.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-rdkafka@2.7.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/VMac/.npm/_logs/2020-09-30T14_35_01_271Z-debug.log
```

When I try running installing `node-gyp` using `npm install -g node-gyp` and run `node-gyp rebuild`, I see the below error

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.0
gyp info using node@10.16.3 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.3 found at "/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [ '/Users/VMac/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/VMac/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/VMac/Library/Caches/node-gyp/10.16.3/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/VMac/Library/Caches/node-gyp/10.16.3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/VMac/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/VMac/Library/Caches/node-gyp/10.16.3/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/VMac/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/VMac/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node" "/Users/VMac/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I also tried `xcode-select --install` but no luck.
Any suggestions on how to fix this and successfully install `node-rdkafka` using npm on my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various options online, I couldn't find the right solution. So, this is what I did and worked

1. Uninstalled `node` following the instructions [here](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/)

   If you are using `Homebrew`, run

   ```
   brew uninstall node
   ```

   Use `--force` or `--ignore-dependencies` if required
2. Run `node -v`. If you still see the version info, follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
3. I also wanted to remove `nvm` from my machine. So, I removed the `~/.nvm` folder. But, I am still seeing the nvm version. To completely clean-up, remove references from `~/.bashrc` and `~/.zshrc` if any

I realised that I had two versions of node

1. Installed manually
2. Installed using Homebrew

Post this, I only installed `nvm` (Don't install node or npm).

```
brew install nvm
```

and then installed the required version of node and npm using

```
nvm install <NODE_VERSION>
```

This solved my `node-gyp` errors

Comment: It was node installation issue or you changed node version?

Answer (score 4):

After hitting this issue myself and trying the solutions proposed in both answers without success this is what worked for me, without the need to uninstall node.

TL:DR

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
npm install node-rdkafka
```

After this I was able to install `node-rdkafka` without any problems.

I had to remove CommandLineTools and reinstall it, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47804075/1016425), because when I tried to run `xcode-select --install` I would get the

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: Just note that in might take up to 30 mins or more

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

> Download the appropriate version of the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" for your version of Catalina from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. As of MacOS 10.15.5, that's Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.5.dmg

From https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md#installing-node-gyp-using-the-xcode-command-line-tools-via-manual-download