# C Code Won't Compile in MacOS Catalina or Big Sur

Tags: c, macos, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur

I am unable to compile C code on neither MacOS Catalina nor Big Sur. I see the header files present in `/usr/include/`, but I get errors from my C compiler.

Current error messages I get from the compiler are:

- For "#include <time.h>" => error: cannot open source file "time.h"
- For "#include <stdint.h>" => error: cannot open source file
  "stdint.h"

What I've tried:

- I tried `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /` and it says "upgrade successful", but does not resolve any errors.
- I tried [uninstalling and reinstalling XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line) (Version 10.1)
- I tried downloading the .pkg file you mentioned (because I was missing it) but was told my macOS version was too new
- The files I need are stored in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`, so we added a [new CPATH and PATH variable (separately) for that path to ~/.bash_profile and /etc/paths](https://medium.com/@youngstone89/setting-up-environment-variables-in-mac-os-28e5941c771c)
- I tried to provide `#include` statements with explicit paths to those files, which quickly spiraled out of control
- I tried to move all of the required files from the above directory to my project folder and changing the paths appropriately in the code
- I tried to run [sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15)
- The files should also be stored in [Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15), so I tried doing the above steps with this path as well

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you!

To provide more clarity based on a comment from Joshua below, these are the steps I followed to set up the 32-bit ARM cross-compiler:

1. `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`
2. ```
    brew install gmp
    brew install mpfr
    brew install libmpc
   ```
3. Downloaded "binutils-2.36.tar.xz" from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/)
4. Outside of the binutils directory, created a directory called
   "build32"
5. ```
    ../binutils-2.36/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --disable-nls --enable-languages=c --without-headers
    make -j4 all
    sudo make install
   ```
6. Downloaded "gcc-arm-src-snapshot-10.2-2020.11.tar.xz" from [here](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads)
7. Inside the main directory, created a subdirectory called "build32"
8. ```
    ../gcc-arm-src-snapshot-10.2-2020.11/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --disable-nls --enable-languages=c --without-headers
    make -j4 all-gcc
    sudo make install-gcc
   ```

Comment: Code? Error message?

Comment: Sure, I'll add some.

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: With ARM 32-bit compiler: 

"make
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -c SDCard.c -o SDCard.o
In file included from SDCard.c:5:
SDCard.h:3:10: fatal error: time.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <time.h> 
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated."

Comment: You see the headers in `/usr/include`?  Congratulations — I've not yet seen them there.  Have you checked that there is any content when you run `wc /usr/include/time.h`?  I'd not be surprised to find it is a broken symlink.  You can see some information in the question [Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrading to Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15) and its answers.  I don't have a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. "wc /usr/include/time.h" returns "198     971    7669 /usr/include/time.h". And I have been referencing various solutions in the link you shared.

Comment: "`arm-none-eabi-gcc`": Your cross-compilation build chain is broken. This isn't going to use the system copies in `/usr/include` but the copies from the target archiecture. While `stdint.h` certainly should exist, it's currently missing.

Comment: The current version of XCode for Mojave (10.14.6 — a predecessor to Catalina 10.15.x and Big Sur 11.1) is 11.3.1; there are newer versions for both Catalina and Big Sur.  Attempting to use Xcode 10.1 on Catalina or Big Sur seems like creating unnecessary hardship for yourself.

Comment: I upgraded to Big Sur and XCode 12.4. Unsurprisingly, the issue has not been magically fixed. 

Is there a recommended way of troubleshooting the cross-compilation build chain?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to a Windows Subsystem for Linux setup on another machine for what I was working on. Another option is to set up a VM on the Mac. I could not figure out another solution for getting it to "just work" on the Mac. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions!

For those looking to pivot to WSL, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) setup guide.

For those looking to go the VM workaround route, this is one process that was graciously recommended to me:

"1. Install Virtualbox from https://www.virtualbox.org/

2. Install Vagrant from https://www.vagrantup.com/
3. Download the prebuilt ARM gcc cross compiler from the link above in my question.
4. Move the download file into the project directory and run the following command to extract it:

   tar -xvf gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz
5. Download [this](https://piazza.com/redirect/s3?bucket=uploads&prefix=paste%2Fjcv05nl6r6u6uf%2Febdd7b43d30a2955f18c9be21ed39fa18e62e1302b9deb5d320ac33d1e5defbd%2FVagrantfile) Vagrantfile (fyi 'this' triggers a download of said file) and move it to the project directory as
   well. This file tells vagrant how to setup the VM. It will mount the
   project directory as well as the SD card. On line 41 of this file it
   tells vagrant where the SD card is located so change the first path
   on this line to where your SD card is located. Additionally, because
   the project directory is mounted, you can still edit the project
   files locally on your machine instead of having to use what's on the
   VM if you use this solution.
6. After all that, you should be ready to create/start the VM using the
   command vagrant up. To log into the VM, vagrant ssh after the
   vagrant up command finishes. Your project files should be located in
   the /vagrant directory. You are now all setup to compile the project
   and if you run make cp it should compile the project and copy it
   over to the SD card.
7. To shutdown the VM you can run vagrant halt to shutdown the VM, and
   to get rid of the VM you can run vagrant destroy. vagrant destroy
   will not delete any of the files that were shared from your computer
   to the VM."