# Compiling bevy_dylib v0.5.0 error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

Tags: rust, bevy

On Mac freshly upgraded to Monterey, I'm getting the following when attempting to `cargo run` a trivial Bevy program. I've reinstalled XCode CLTs like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line) and other places. I've tried messing around with some of the cargo.yml with no success.

```
   Compiling bevy_dylib v0.5.0
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
 note: "cc" "-Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/var/folders/rp/lky8r76j5v5dk0rqg_yzk35w0000gn/T/rustcDYBmaq/list" 
"-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" <......... many pages of warnings>
ld: warning: object file (/Users/BWStearns/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bevy-glsl-to-spirv-0.2.1/build/osx/libSPIRV-Tools-opt.glsltospirv.a(const_folding_rules.cpp.o)) was built for newer macOS version (10.13) than being linked (10.7)
<many more pages of warnings>
            "_CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID", referenced from:
                _$LT$winit..platform_impl..platform..monitor..MonitorHandle$u20$as$u20$core..cmp..PartialEq$GT$::eq::h541b069daf520ec9 in libwinit-4f8b93ad49cc21f8.rlib(winit-4f8b93ad49cc21f8.winit.355ded65-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
                _$LT$winit..platform_impl..platform..monitor..MonitorHandle$u20$as$u20$core..cmp..Ord$GT$::cmp::h951d61f6bd1d7a5f in libwinit-4f8b93ad49cc21f8.rlib(winit-4f8b93ad49cc21f8.winit.355ded65-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
                winit::platform_impl::platform::monitor::MonitorHandle::ns_screen::h3207f8aed4eae22f in libwinit-4f8b93ad49cc21f8.rlib(winit-4f8b93ad49cc21f8.winit.355ded65-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          

error: could not compile `bevy_dylib` due to previous error
```

The cargo.yml is like this:

```
[package]
name = "my_bevy_game"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
bevy = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["dynamic"] }
```

I just ran into this starting this week. I am pretty sure this exact code was compiling fine a couple weeks ago. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

main.rs looks like

```
use bevy::prelude::*;

struct Person;

struct Name(String);

fn add_people(mut commands: Commands) {
    commands.spawn().insert(Person).insert(Name("Elaina Proctor".to_string()));
    commands.spawn().insert(Person).insert(Name("Renzo Hume".to_string()));
    commands.spawn().insert(Person).insert(Name("Zayna Nieves".to_string()));
}

fn greet_people(query: Query<&Name, With<Person>>) {
    for name in query.iter() {
        println!("hello {}!", name.0);
    }
}

pub struct HelloPlugin;

impl Plugin for HelloPlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: &mut AppBuilder) {
        app.add_startup_system(add_people.system())
            .add_system(greet_people.system());
    }
}

fn main() {
    App::build()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_plugin(HelloPlugin)
        .run();
}
```

Update:

Definitely something about the environment on my machine because on a different macbook it worked fine.

Comment: If you don't use the dylib, does the program compile?

Comment: How could I opt out of that?

Comment: remove `features = ["dynamic"]` from your cargo.toml

Comment: Even after `cargo clean` removing `["dynamic"]` and calling `cargo run` still yields `   Compiling my_bevy_game v0.1.0 (/Users/brianstearns/rust/my_bevy_game)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1`

Comment: Does it yield the same error? If so, does deleting the cargo.lock change anything?

Comment: Same error after running `cargo run` after `cargo clean` or `rm Cargo.lock`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239967/discussion-between-aiden4-and-bwstearns).

Comment: This appears to be a new bug and/or "feature" in rust. https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/3313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found *a* solution if you discover this issue and the code works on other machines. Uninstall rust with `rustup self uninstall` and then renistall with the standard script `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh` and then you should be good.