# Mac cmake: 'stdio.h' file not found

Tags: macos, cmake, stdio

I have been stuck on this for a while, and I was wondering if I could get some help.

I'm currently stuck trying to run a cmake setup file and I'm constantly getting this error

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:107:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
```

I've been looking online, and haven't been able to find anything recent. I've tried using the xcode-select --install already.

cmake version is currently 3.21.3.

The library I'm trying to install is https://github.com/google/draco, where I'm trying to install python functions using pybind11. I was able to install this library through cmake, whoever when I try to install the pybind11 functionality I keep getting this error. This library seemed to function properly on a coworkers linux machine, and they were running cmake 3.20.4 on ubuntu 18.04 (I don't know if this makes a difference)

Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if there's any other information that can help the process.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something in XCode has changed after updating MacOS to 12.3. I had to reinstall XCode command line tools. I don't say it's right solution, but it works for me.

Commands for reinstalling (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47804075):

1. removing the old tools (`$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`)
2. install xcode command line tools again (`$ xcode-select --install`).

Comment: On macOS 13.2.1 this worked for me. Thanks.